# Validating XML with RelaxNG and SAX

Tags: xml, sax, saxparser, relaxng

I am trying to parse and validate an XML file against an RelaxNG schema using SAX.  I have the following code:

```java
      System.setProperty(SchemaFactory.class.getName() + ":" + XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI, "com.thaiopensource.relaxng.jaxp.XMLSyntaxSchemaFactory"); 
      SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.RELAXNG_NS_URI);
      Schema schema = sf.newSchema(scf);
      SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
       factory.setSchema(schema);

      try {
     SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser ();
     XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader ();
         reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
         reader.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation",
                            schemaFilename);
         reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude", true);
         reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);
         reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude/fixup-base-uris", false);
         reader.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
         
     reader.setErrorHandler   (this);
     reader.setContentHandler (this);
     reader.setEntityResolver (this);

         reader.parse (new InputSource(input));
```

but when I run this I get the error

```
Document is invalid: no grammar found.
```

The document and the schema both validate correctly using jing.  Also, if I use trang to convert my schema to xsd and use that instead of rng, everything works correctly.

I suspect that when I instantiate the SAXParserFactory object I need to specify that I want a RelaxNG parser factory.  The documentation on the [relaxng.org site](https://relaxng.org) mentions "Can be used as a library for validation with any SAX2 parser", but the documentation link is broken.   I have looked around the [jing-trang-relaxng code](https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang) and I cannot find a class with a name like `'.*ParseFactory.*'` anywhere.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `ValidationHandler` from your `Schema` e.g. `ValidatorHandler validatorHandler = schema.newValidatorHandler();`. That `ValidationHandler` can then be set on the `XMLReader reader` as the `ContentHandler`: `reader.setContentHandler(validatorHandler);`. You can also set it as the `DTDHandler` with e.g. `reader.setDTDHandler((DTDHandler)validatorHandler);`.